# how to disable TLS 1.0 and checking enabling SSl 3.0 in Firefox 27.0.1?

Tags: firefox, ssh, https, tls

How to disable TLS 1.0 and checking enabling SSL 3.0 in Firefox 27.0.1 (new Version) ?

I suppose I can find it at the Encryption tab.

I followed below path Tools -> Options -> Advanced

but there was not the tab anymore.

Comment: What's the rationale behind this? It's not exactly a "best practice"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost anything can be configured in about:config. [This also includes allowed TLS versions.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*)

- `security.tls.version.min` specifies the minimum allowed protocol version
- `security.tls.version.max` specifies the maximum allowed protocol version

Acceptable values for these options:

- `0` – SSLv3
- `1` – TLS 1.0
- `2` – TLS 1.1
- `3` – TLS 1.2

Also, as noted in the linked article, the GUI options are gone since Firefox 23.