# Port forwarding does not work for http sites

Tags: ssl, ssh, proxy, firefox

I am connecting to office network through VPN. I have two servers A and B. I have ssh tomcat access to A through VPN but not to B. When I ssh into A, from there I can ssh into B. Also, B is running tomcat, which I can see though elinks on A.

I want to see the tomcat page of B on my remote machine browser. So I followed the instructions mentioned in [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/347499/how-to-assign-a-hostname-to-ssh-tunnel). I ssh-ed into A using ssh user@A -D 1234, changed firefox proxy settings to localhost:1234. But instead of the tomcat page on B, I keep getting "The connection was reset" error on firefox. ([image: see attached image])

I see that https sites work perfectly, whereas other sites throw the same "The connection was reset" error. Is there any way of getting around this? Following a suggestion in [this ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1175163), I tried [disabling tls in firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/718814/how-to-disable-tls-1-0-and-checking-enabling-ssl-3-0-in-firefox-27-0-1) but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably set it as an HTTP proxy, not a SOCKS proxy.  Make sure you've selected it as a SOCKS proxy.